# como pasar un valor que se selecciona en una lista a una ventana modal en angular

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-material

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]espero puedan ayudarme, estoy varias intentando hacer esto, no soy programadora, mas conozco de java y todavia no le entiendo mucho el typescript, bueno aqui pueden ver el codigo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-79qxki-vqsruq?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts

Quisiera que aparesca el nombre seleccionado en la ventana modal, mas no consigo, espero puedan orientarme, muchas gracias.

voy a dar mas detalle:
las clases las funciones estan en "dialog-overview-example.ts", la pagina principal en "dialog-overview-example.html", la pagina fluctuante o modal en "dialog-overview-example-dialog.html" y los estilos en "dialog-overview-example.css"

en la pagina de ts cree un array de usuarios, dado que tome de otro ejemplo, mas no importa mucho el nombre..

Comment: Debes pasar como parametro el elemento seleccionado al **openDialog()**, de esa forma recibes en el componente el valor; despues simplemente lo muestras en el modal reemplazando __Hi {{usuario.nombre}} __ por __Hi {{data.name}}__ .

Answer (score 1):

Como estas! La interface DialogData es el nexo entre la ventana "padre" y la modal.
En el ts seria asi:

```
 openDialog(user: any): void {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px',
  data: {name: user.id, animal: user.nombre}
});
```

y en el html

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="2:1">
  <div *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios" (click)="openDialog(usuario)">
    <mat-grid-tile> {{usuario.nombre}}</mat-grid-tile>
      </div>
</mat-grid-list>
```

me falto el dialog!

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.animal}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>Usuario</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.name">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```